# How many packs are recommended in webpacker Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I am using webpacker and I saw that as I increased the number of Packs, the build time increased significantly. I reduced to just one for now. But I want to know if there is an ideal number I can go with without hampering the build time in development and production.

With 4 packs the build time was 7 seconds,
with 1 pack it's 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no recommended number of files for the webpacker.

The build time of webpacker is directly proportional to the number dependencies and size of the pack file rather than the number of files. But, with the increase in number files it may increase time to build source maps for the files which is negligible.

If you want to increase the performance in build times, you can consider increasing ram size and better CPU.

And I suggest it's not always a good idea to merge multiple pack files just for the sake of build time as there won't be any performance improvements between a single file and multiple packs files in terms of size and delivery of the web request. Always build page specific or layout specific pack files.